# Copying a JavaScript array of objects is not working

Tags: typescript, angular6

It seems like it should work based on my research but it is not working. Where am I missing the point or what don't I know?

Here is my code:

```typescript
import { Menu } from '../../../menu.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-top-menu',
    templateUrl: './top-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top-menu.component.scss']
})
export class TopMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    menuList: Menu[] = [];
    constructor(private mb: MessageServiceBus) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mb.subjTopMenu.subscribe((mnu: Menu[]) = {
/* 16 */    console.log(mnu);
/* 17 */    this.menuList = mnu.slice();
/* 18 */    this.menuList = mnu.slice(0);
/* 19 */    mnu.forEach(el => {
/* 20 */        this.menuList.push(el);
/* 21 */    });
/* 22 */    console.log(this.menuList);    
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is in the **ngOnInit** method.

- Line 16: displays correct data as shown in the debug console
- Line 17 & 18: are done to see if any of them will copy into `menuList`
- Lines 18 - 21: are done to see if this will copy
- Line 22: to see value of `menuList` - this shows undefined!

Please help.

Comment: What result do you get and what result do you want? Why do you `slice` `mnu` before pushing `mnu` elements?

Comment: i was simply trying different ways of pushing mnu into menuList.  All i need is one of those.  Outside of debugging inside of VS Code - any of those work.  Thanks for taking a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It turns, this works - BUT not when inspecting the variables in VS Code debug.  I think the instance variables go out of scope